# Rails namespacing concerns based on model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, separation-of-concerns

I am looking to separate concerns for some subset of function specific to a model.
I have referenced [here](http://yosriady.com/2015/04/11/refactoring-fat-rails-models/) and followed this pattern

```
module ModelName::ConcernName
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # class macros
  end

  # instance methods
  def some_instance_method

  end

  module ClassMethods
    # class methods here, self included
  end
end
```

However, when I try to start the server it would result in the following error

> Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ModelName::ConcernName

I am wondering what is the best way to do concerns for some subset functions of a model.

**Edit**

Providing the model code: 
path: app/models/rent.rb

Now I have a lot of checking logic in my model

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
    def pricing_ready?
        # check if pricing is ready
    end

    def photos_ready?
        # check if photo is ready
    end

    def availability_ready?
        # check if availability setting is ready
    end

    def features_ready?
        # check if features are set
    end
end
```

I want to separate it in concern

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Rent::Readiness
end
```

And organise the concern by namespace
path: app/models/concerns/rent/readiness.rb

```
module Rent::Readiness
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # class macros
  end

  # instance methods
  def pricing_ready?
    # check if pricing is ready
  end

  ...

  module ClassMethods
    # class methods here, self included
  end
end
```

Now I got it working if I just do class `RentReadiness` with the path in `app/models/concerns/rent_readiness.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails uses activesupport to load classes and modules as they are defined by inferring the file path based on the class or module name, this is done as the Ruby parser loads your files and come across a new constant that has not been loaded yet. In your case, the `Rent` model is parsed up to the `Rent::Readlines` reference, at which point activesupport goes off to look for the `rent/readlines.rb` code file that matches the name. This file is then then parsed by ruby, but on the first line, The still unloaded `Rent` class is referenced, which triggers activesupport to go off and look for the code file that matches the name.

Comment: How should I tackle this problem then?

Comment: First off, the Rails concerns pattern is designed so that each concern should be available to any model, updating your readlines concern to achieve  this would remove the need to namespace it in the first place. Otherwise, if this truly is logic that is only relevant to the Rent model, the I'd maybe move thus to /lib and rename it RentReadlines (it can still use the concern extension to help the syntax)

Comment: what is the reason behind moving it to lib?

Comment: What he means is: Concerns are made to be applied to two or more models. If you want to separate one model's specifics methods, usually the pattern to do that, is to write the methods into a separated class, put it in /lib and then include this class is the model.

Comment: Yes, as @lcguida has pointed out, the pattern to move a models methods out of the class is to move them into a module and have that located in `/lib`. the reason to use `/lib`? Rails doesn't have a default location to store these kinds of file, they don't fit in MVC, so `/lib` is the next best place, as other programmers will understand that they're important code files, but that they don't fit into the standard Rails locations. Of cause you can put these files anywhere you like, but that will make it harder for new programmers to the project understand your intentions.

Answer (score 8):

You can scope it to `Rents` and place to `concerns/rents/readiness.rb`:

```
module Rents
  module Readiness
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      # class macros
    end
  end
end
```

And in model:

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rents::Readiness
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make it work by just moving the folder with model-specific concerns from `concerns` to `models`. So, you would have:

```
models/
    rent.rb
    rent/
        readiness.rb
```

I like this convention of using the model as the namespace for its concerns because it lets you remove some redundancy from code:

- Since you are defining the concern within the model class, in the model you can write `include Readiness` instead of `include Rent::Readiness`
- When defining the concern, you can use `module Rent::Readiness` instead of

  ```
  class Rent < ApplicationRecord
       module Readiness
  ...
  ```

  Which would be another way of fixing the circular dependency problem you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Jorge, it worked for me. Is this the type of directory structure you use at Basecamp? With the namespaced concern under `models` rather than the `concerns` directory?

Comment: I believe the answer to my question above is yes, as per a [tweet](https://twitter.com/dhh/status/964864438938492930) from DHH.